# Scrum: too much or not enough?

Tags: project-management, process, agile, scrum

My company has recently started using Scrum; we've done 2 sprints. We're still learning, but we've definitely exposed and fixed some problems in our development process already. So in general I think it has been good for us.

In reading many of the internet musings about Scrum from evangelists, cynics and everyone in between, three common and somewhat contradictory themes have stood out to me:

1. Scrum implementation fails because the processes of Scrum are not followed closely enough.
2. Scrum implementation fails because the organization does not adapt Scrum to its own environment/culture/practices.
3. The processes of Scrum are not important; only the values in the Agile Manifesto matter.

Examples of these can be seen in the responses to these SO questions:

- [Have you had a bad experience with Scrum or Sprinting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272253/have-you-had-a-bad-experience-with-scrum-or-sprinting)
- [Is Scrum evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343162/is-scrum-evil)
- [Is Agile Development Dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301993/is-agile-development-dead)

I have to admit that we're not yet following all the guidelines of Scrum: we haven't done a release at the end of the sprints, our Scrum Master doesn't want us to move tasks out of the sprint backlog near the end of the sprint so that he can see how much our planning was off (which means the burndown chart never goes to 0), and urgent customer support issues still have incredible power to disrupt everyone's planning, for a few examples.

**My question is:** in trying to solve these and other issues, is it better to try and be closer to the official Scrum processes, better to be closer to some of our pre-Scrum processes, or better to meditate on the principles of Scrum to try and come up with a different process altogether?

Comment: One main concern with scrum is; the customer. Many customers see scrum as a "bad" and insecure way for working.

Comment: With only a couple of sprints done, I'd be tempted to not try to read too much into the results as not everything works great on the first try.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say that you are really missing one of the key components of agility if you don't release early and often.  To the degree that you don't do this, your process is not agile and bound to suffer the same sorts of problems that traditional, plan-driven processes have.  It may be that this is a temporary condition as you are just getting used to things, but you need to start releasing soon (and regularly).

You'll always have the problem with show-stoppers, but you may be able to help this by shortening your sprint length.  The customer may not be able to wait a month, but they may be able to wait 2 weeks for some things.  A shorter sprint length, then, may help you to defer some requests to the next sprint making them less disruptive.  You also need to be upfront with the customer that the disruptions are actually causing your pace to suffer.  They may voluntarily choose to wait if they know that their chosen features are being delayed by some requests.

Another observation that I would make is that, as with almost anything, it's better to start out by following the pattern as closely as you can while you are learning.  Once you have a good grasp of the fundamental principles, you can then see where some principles can be bent, broken, or replaced much more clearly to improve the process.  Until you really get it, the things you change may hurt or help -- you really have no idea since you don't have the experience that tells you how things ought to be working.  Unless your Scrum master is really experienced, you may want to hew closer to the defined practices until you've got a few more sprints under your belt.

Comment: +1: Focus on Agility; legacy processes are almost always impediments.

Comment: I was trying not to betray my biases in my question, but I agree with you :D I'm hoping for some recommendations for improvements that I can take to the Scrum Master and the contradictions in the Scrum commentary I've read have made me feel less confident in my opinions.

Comment: One thing to note is that releasing often doesn't have to mean updating production, just having something that is eligible for a production release, forcing you to regular have 'production ready' code.

Comment: Not actually releasing to customers deprives you of valuable feedback.  I'd at least want to release to some beta customers regularly.  Once the app becomes stable, releasing to production becomes more and more desirable.

Answer (score 5):

Almost everything I've read on Scrum says that one of the keys is to adapt the process to fit your own situation.  No two development teams are the same, and different things work for different people.

The main ideas behind Scrum are:

*Have a tight feedback loop from requirements to development and back to the stakeholder(s).*

This allows the development team to continually verify that they are building something that's actually wanted and allows the development to be easily adjusted as requirements and expectations change.  Stakeholders can add or remove features at any point and they can adjust the priority of the features as their needs change.

*Keep the software in a state where it's releasable at the end of any given sprint.*

That's not to say you have releases every sprint, but that you could if the customer decides they want to have the latest stuff.  This also helps a development team avoid the situation of integration hell that comes from people going off and working on a piece of the project on for months at a time in isolation.

*Be completely transparent with what's going on in development and everyone needs to be willing to make tradeoffs.*

This is where most projects fail and where Scrum can really succeed if everyone buys into the process.  So many development projects are set up to where a release has to have X features released on Y date and no flexibility in changing that.  This results in half-done features and bug ridden software as the developers cram to get in all the required features on their checklist.

The reality is, unexpected things happen in software development.  With open communication and willing participants in the Scrum process, customers and developers can continually evaluate the current state of the project and make educated decisions on prioritizing the work remaining on the project.

Answer (score 2):

Scrum *does* work. Not with all teams in all situations, but it has been shown to work.

I would suggest trying to embrace textbook Scrum as much as your business environment allows, see how that works out, *and then tune it*.

Why does your Scrum master not want to move tasks out of the sprint backlog? Does he not 100% embrace the principles of Scrum? (I would see that as worrying in a Scrum master)

Most problems implementing Scrum are actually just problems in the team or business being exposed by the Scrum process e.g. - if your sprints are thrown out by unforeseen support issues this suggests you are not allocating enough resource to support

Comment: +1: Don't "optimize" Scrum by tuning it to look more like your legacy processes.  If your legacy processes were so good, why not just continue with them?  If they're not good, discard them and rebuild from scratch.

Comment: Not sure if it's not embracing or understanding the principles; he likes the productivity data and statistics best, I think. He's coming from a PM role.

I'd like to push for more Scrum principles but I'm not confident enough and the contradictions in the Scrum lit aren't helping.

Comment: @carolclarinet: Don't get fooled by "the contradictions in the Scrum lit"  Most of that is from people who did something they called Scrum but had no Agile features at all.  "Scrum, Misapplied" is what James Shore calls it.  There are no contradictions, just people doing Agile badly.

Answer (score 1):

Every company is different, every project is different and every client is different.

I think it's just as easy to fail by following scrum (or any other methodology) too closely in an environment that doesn't fit the methodology as it is to fail because you follow scrum too loosely in a project that does fit.

At the end some generic answer in a QA site is no replacement to serious analysis of your own project, company, team and clients - there is no magic formula and you have to make your own decision.

Comment: I know this is a tough question for SO to answer definitively for me. I suppose I'm a typical CS type wanting a black and white answer in a gray area ;) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** You need to adopt both Scrum and XP together to get the full benefits of scrum.

**Reasons:**

The reasons are based on years of doing XP and scrum, and specifically on what I learned from Jeff Sutherland's talk (for the ACCU in London, May 2009)

- **Scrum is a management technique** - not necessarily a software production method. Some people use scrum in other domains e.g. preparing museum exhibitions and running religious institutions... so it has the mechanisms you need to make a multidisciplinary team deliver work adaptably in small increments.
- **Scrum, originally included all the extreme programming practices**. Jeff Sutherland actually said that *he's never seen a scrum project achieve the higher orders of productivity measured for scrum without using the extreme programming practices.*
- **Scrum and XP both come from the same background** - Object-oriented programming, specifically with Smalltalk. The programmers went off and developed XP whilst the management people created scrum. You need both aspects - development practices and management practices.
- **The XP practices were deliberately removed from Scrum to make it easier to adopt.** - Implementing the XP practices is hard and it's difficult to get them adopted quickly. Jeff actually said that Ken Schwaber removed the XP practices to help people get started with scrum. The danger now is that this minimal scrum has become all that people see and expect.
- **Lots of non-technical project managers now teach scrum - but they don't have the skillset to teach XP**
- **Not all developers find the XP practices easy to adopt** - they can be hard sell and it takes a few months rather than the 2 days it takes to establish basic scrum.

Answer (score 1):

**Scrum doesn't attempt to address the technical issues** in software development. It's just a small management process.

- The **strength of scrum is that it doesn't get in the way** by prescribing lots of unnecessary or irrelevant technical work.
- The **weakness of scrum is that it doesn't tell you what good technical practices to do.**

**Extreme Programming does address the technical issues involved** in software development and it fits very well within scrum. The reason the scrum people didn't force everyone to do the XP technical practices is that **it takes about 6 months to implement those tech practices, rather than the 2 days it takes to implement the most basic scrum.**

Whether or not scrum is "evil" - there are certainly drawbacks with it. **We discussed the uneasy relationship between XP and Scrum at length at XP Days, London, 2009:** http://xpday-london.editme.com/WhereHasXpGone

Answer (score 0):

Scrum is not really the problem that you are showing.  Most development methodologies work, even waterfall, as much as we like to bash it, works.  Scrum does make you concentrate a little more on the important things, but it won't stop people from making bad decisions like not really following the process.

The system is pretty simple at its core.

See the problem.
Define what done is.
Create a series of tasks that will get you to done.
Estimate those tasks.
Select enough of those so that you can get something done in a short period of time.
Complete the tasks.
Rinse and repeat.

OK admittedly these steps are simplified, and I haven't thrown in a scrum master and a customer.  But the point is that the framework is just a basic time management strategy.  If the people in your system are chaotic and not good at getting things done then scrum really won't help them.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to start applying Scrum by the book, and to **really understand the underlying principles and values** from the [Agile manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/), prior to customize it, so that the process does not get denatured. Be sure to run [retrospectives](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/dlret/agile-retrospectives) at the end of each and every iteration (Sprint) to "*inspect and adapt*" your process and *eliminate waste*.

For your Scrum Master, he can track what is removed from the current Sprint. Also Sprints are planned based on the previous Sprints achievement, not on what was previously scheduled. I do no get its point.

Comment: I don't really get the point either; I'm trying to convince him that it's not a good thing. He seems to really like the data and statistics that come from the burndown chart, including how much mis-planning there was. Once he's done with his analysis, we move undone tasks to the next sprint.